# Azure Mobile services, C# backend get actually user access token for provider

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-mobile-services

Im writing an ios app, I have a c# mobile services back end.

Its essential to my app to be able to get the actual token for interacting with facebook graph api, google etc...

I need to be able to post the users social media channels if they choose to.

I need the c# back end because im making use of the owin lib. I know the getidenties() method in js does what i need. do i need to do a custom sort of linkedIn flow for the inbuilt type to get this info? would that even work?

thank you in advance

John Harris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the backend side controller, you can grab the token from the current user...

try something like this:

```
        var serviceUser = this.User as ServiceUser;
        var identities = await serviceUser.GetIdentitiesAsync();
        var fbIdentity = identities.OfType<FacebookCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();

        //do whatever you want with the token
        var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(fbIdentity.AccessToken);
        dynamic myProfile = await facebookClient.GetTaskAsync("/me");
```